# How can i optimize this dijkstra structure code?

Tags: c++, graph, shortest-path

This is the dijkstra structure i am using :(however the MAXV(which is maximum number of vertices is maximum at 500 and every time i try to change it to something more than this it generates and error when running )

-I want to use this way to represent a graph with 10000 vertices, does anyone know how to optimize it ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
#define MAXV 500
#define MAXINT 99999
typedef struct{
        int next;
        int weight;
}edge;
typedef struct{
        edge edges[MAXV][MAXV];
        int nedges;
        int nvertices;
        int ndegree[MAXV];
}graph;
```

and this is my dijkstra code:

```
int dijkstra(graph *g,int start,int end){
    int distance[MAXV];
    bool intree[MAXV];
    for(int i=0;i<=MAXV;++i){
            intree[i]=false;
            distance[i]=MAXINT;
    }
    int v=start;
    distance[v]=0;
    while(intree[v]==false){
           intree[v]=true;
           for(int i=0;i<g->ndegree[v];++i){
                   int cand=g->edges[v][i].next;
                   int weight=g->edges[v][i].weight;
                   if(distance[cand] > distance[v]+weight){
                           distance[cand] = distance[v]+weight;
                   }
           }
           int dist=MAXINT;
           for(int i=0;i<g->nvertices;++i){
                   if((intree[i]==false) && (dist > distance[i])){
                           dist=distance[i];
                            v=i;
                   }
           }
    }
    return distance[end];
}
```

Comment: Tip: Prefer `const int MaxV = 500;`. It's more typesafe and easier to debug.

Comment: I don't see any check for NULL pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [adjacency lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) for storing the graph. Right now you're using an [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix), which means that you allocate `MAXV*MAXV*sizeof(edge)` bytes just for that. That's a lot when `MAXV` is `10 000`, so you're probably getting a segmentation fault. Switching to adjacency lists will get rid of the error.

However, even with adjacency lists, the Dijkstra algorithm you have right now is `O(n^2)` where `n` is the number of nodes. That's still a lot for `10 000` nodes. Consider implementing [Dijkstra with heaps](http://www.cse.hut.fi/en/research/SVG/TRAKLA2/exercises/Dijkstra_Heap.html) (also [here](http://www.srcf.ucam.org/algorithms/notes/dijkstra_with_heaps.pdf)) if you have to support this many nodes.

Comment: `10000 * 10000 * 8` may look a lot, but it's less than 800 MB. That's unlikely to segfault. And with proper malloc handling (not shown) it won't fault at all. It's also possible that the code suffers from a Stack Overflow, of course.

Comment: @MSalters - yes, but 800 MB is still a lot when you can get away with a lot less by switching to adjacency lists, which will also make most graph algorithms a lot faster.